# Capacitor with dielectric between the plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, capacitance, dielectric

Let's assume we have a capacitor of capacitance $C$ and potential difference $U$. After charging it we disconnect it. Then we put a dielectric between the plates. I know that capacitance will increase by $C * k$, however what happens with the charge and potential difference on it.

Let's say $k = 2$. Will $q$ double or will $ U $decrease to a half ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plates are disconnected, the charge has nowhere to go.  Rather `U` will have to change.  What happens is the charged capacitor does work on the dielectric (pulling it in), resulting in a change in the energy stored in the capacitor.

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please explain further what you mean with "pulling it in" ?

Comment: Sure.  The charge of the plates causes the dielectric to become polarized: positive charges in the dielectric get pulled a little bit towards the negative plate, and negative charges in the dielectric get pulled a little bit towards the positive plate.  These induced dipoles in the dielectric are attracted by the electric field of the plates.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused now. According to page 5-22 of http://web.mit.edu/viz/EM/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide05.pdf, the voltage is observed to decrease by a factor of $k$, but the capacitance increases by a factor of $k$. This means that energy $\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ decreases by a factor of $k$. Somehow that seems strange, is that correct? According to question 3 of https://ilt.seas.harvard.edu/students/lectures/printablelecture/?PHPSESSID=&lectureID=8985, this is the case...

Comment: E = 1/2 * q * U  so energy decreases by factor of k. The equation you stated is obtained by q = C * U, U and C being the initial potential difference and capacitance. I apologize if I'm incorrect.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus That sounds right to me.  Why does it seem strange?

Comment: The typical explanation for why the energy decreases is due to the fact that mechanical work is expended while inserting the dielectric due to the fact that there is an attractive force between the plates and the dielectric (due to monopole induced-dipole attraction).

Comment: However, since energy is a state function, we have that the energy released when discharging the vacuum capacitor must be the same as the sum of the energy done while inserting the dielectric into the capacitor plus the energy released when the dielectric-filled capacitor discharges plus the energy done while removing the dielectric from the discharged capacitor.

Comment: I initially thought that the work required to remove the dielectric from the uncharged capacitor was zero, since the plate voltage was zero, and hence the field between the plates is zero, and hence (assuming a linear dielectric) the induced dipole density is zero, and thus there is no attractive force between the plates and the dielectric, and so no work is required to remove it. But obviously that's wrong, since if that's zero, it violates conservation of energy.

Comment: Another question guys, if the capacitor was still connected then the charge would double, correct?

Comment: @user1949350: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: this answeris wrong. rather, the capacitor will repel the dielectric as it is being inserted.

Comment: @guru Sorry, I believe you are incorrect.  You get an attraction from inducing dipoles in the dielectric.  The negative charges in the dielectric are pulled closer to the positive plate, so their attraction to it outweighs the repulsion felt by the more distant positive charges.  Likewise, the positive charges are pulled closer to the negative plate, so their attraction towards it outweighs the repulsion felt by the more distant negative charges.